# Wifi USB stick not working on PC running Windows 10 but works on laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, windows-10

I have bought a 4G LTE Wifi USB stick (Huawei E3372, CE0197).

When I plug it on my laptop running Windows 10 I get instantly Internet access, but when I plug it to my PC running the same Windows version I get a warning saying that the Internet USB cable is not recognized.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked if the drivers are properly installed?

Comment: Are you using the correct type of USB port?  In other words if the Huawei E3372 is a USB 3.0 in both cases are you using a USB 3.0 port?

Comment: There are numerous tools that will display what speed a USB device is connected at.  Just use one of those.  Simplest solution, to determine the answer to my question, is to look at the specification of the device then visual inspect what type of port your using.

Comment: @Ramhound This is a **Wifi** USB stick, I tried on Ubuntu to check its speed but it is not even displayed in /media/myhome/

Comment: A USB device is a USB Device.  I am not sure what your comment is trying to address.  It still requires a certain amount of power.  If it is a USB 3.0 device it cannot be plugged into a USB 2.0 and expected to work.  The fact it isn't being recognized indicates there is an incompatibility between it and the laptop.

Comment: @Ramhound You were definitely right: I checked on HP website the model of my machine and I guess the 4 USB ports it supports are only of type USB 2.0 but my USB is 3.0. If you summerize your comment as an answer I will validate it. Thank you very much for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

The four USB ports of my machine are of type `USB 2.0` whereas my USB Wi-Fi stick is of type `USB 3.0`. That is the reason of the issue I faced.